# preg_match to validate a URL slug

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am letting the user create their own profile on my site so they can choose what their url will be. So for example if their name is John Smith they might like to enter john-smith and then their profile URL would be www.mysite.com/john-smith.

I need to use preg_match to validate that what they enter is a valid URL slug. So here are the rules that it must fulfill to be valid:

it must contain at least one letter and it can only contain letters, numbers and hyphens

Can someone help me out please I am good at PHP but rubbish with regex!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I hope this code is self-explanatory:

```
<?php

function test_username($username){
    if(preg_match('/^[a-z][-a-z0-9]*$/', $username)){
        echo "$username matches!\n";
    } else {
        echo "$username does not match!\n";
    }
}

test_username("user-n4me");
test_username("user+inv@lid")
```

But if not, the function test_username() test its argument against the pattern:

- begins (`^`) ...
- with one letter (`[a-z]`) ...
- followed by any number of letters, numbers or hyphens (`[-a-z0-9]*`) ...
- and doesn't have anything after that (`$`).

Comment: This fails for `invalid--slug`

Comment: @Victor, you can try: /^[a-z](-[a-z0-9]+)*$/

Comment: @ArthurRonconi this works better : /^[a-z]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*$/

Answer (score 6):

Better solution:

```
function is_slug($str) {
    return preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+(-?[a-z0-9]+)*$/i', $str);
}
```

Tests:

- fail: -user-name
- fail: user--name
- fail: username-
- valid: user-name
- valid: user123-name-321
- valid: username
- valid: USER123-name
- valid: user-name-2

Enjoy!

Comment: something wrong, not match with `user-name`, only `u-name` https://regex101.com/r/0hYjoV/1

Comment: @ArthurShlain thanks. It's fixed, try again please.

Comment: Now better, but check this variant: user-name-2

Comment: @ArthurShlain fixed again =)

Comment: How to allow underscore also with this ? Same rule need to apply as with dash, cannot occur in start/end, but can in the middle.

Comment: @VickyDev /^[a-z0-9]+([-_]?[a-z0-9]+)*$/i

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simply, if we assume that the first character must be a letter...

```
/[a-z]{1}[a-z0-9\-]*/i
```